# Attaching a file when opening outlook

Tags: java, eclipse, outlook, attachment

My program opens outlook and is supposed to attach a file when the app opens but when it does it gives me

> error : cannot open file because it is not associated with default
>   identity.

I have tried several things like just setting one default identity but the error remains, what can I do? I am working in Eclipse on a Mac.

```
new ProcessBuilder("/Applications/MicrosoftOutlook.app/Contents/MacOS/MicrosoftOutlook","/a","/Users/name/Desktop/"+num+"/1.pdf").start();
```

Comment: You should probably edit your name out of the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ProcessBuilder("/Applications/MicrosoftOutlook.app/Contents/MacOS/MicrosoftOutlook","/a","/Users/paulinavazquezcontreras/Desktop/"+num+"/1.pdf").start();
```

In this line, you need to take the username of the system and replace "paulinavaazquezcontreras" with that.

To obtain the username, use this.

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```